# can't find '__main__' module for Json file Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to render a json file but it doesn't seem to be working. The error states "can't find '**main**' module in '/Users/tgiedraitis/PycharmProjects/GDP Visulization' ".The value equal to the filename I received from the website of the project I'm working on.
If you want to see the data and where I got the filename, go to https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/solutions/chapter_16.html. Then under Solutions-Chapter 16, click "16-6 Gross Domestic Product", and then click "here". Finally, I clicked "highlight" and copied the link "// [https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/resources/global_gdp.json"](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/resources/global_gdp.json%22) for my filename value. Ive made sure my script path and working directory are set to the right values but the error remains. Could someone please help me fix this issue. Thanks.

```
import json
filename = "//https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/resources/global_gdp.json"

with open(filename) as f:
    gpd_data = json.load(f)

for gpd_dict in gpd_data:
    if gpd_dict ["Year"]  == "2014":
        country_name = gpd_dict["Country Name"]
        country_code = gpd_dict["Country Code"]
        print(country_name + ":" + country_code)
```

Comment: Your passing a link as a path. You can download the json file and then pass it as file path.

Comment: How would I go about downlaoding the Json file? The place where I found the data offers no way to download the data. I've tried copying and pasting the data into a file in my text editor (Pycharms) and then giving the filename the path of that file but I get the same error. I'm on a mac if that helps.

Comment: You can create a file called `data.json` and copy and paste the json values in that file and point the file path to the variable `filename`. Hope it fixes the issue :)

Comment: Hmm... I believe I did that and still got the same error: "can't find '__main__' module in '/Users/tgiedraitis/PycharmProjects/GDP Visualization"  I edited my code so it now looks like this: "filename = "/Users/tgiedraitis/PycharmProjects/GDP Visulization/data.json".

Comment: There is noting wrong with the json file I think there is something wrong with your code can you please post the entire code.

Comment: 'import json'
filename = "/Users/tgiedraitis/PycharmProjects/GDP Visulization/main.json"
with open(filename) as f:
    gpd_data = json.load(f)

for gpd_dict in gpd_data:
    if gpd_dict ["Year"]  == "2014":
        country_name = gpd_dict["Country Name"]
        country_code = gpd_dict["Country Code"]
        print(country_name + ":" + country_code)"